# How to add text to a C# datagrid from a textbox using a button click

Tags: c#, gridview

How to add text to a C# datagrid from a textbox using a button click

Comment: It's easier to help if you post some code of what you have tried.

Comment: winforms, wpf or silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't make any sense please mention your need so that i can give a try, if you just want to add what you have typed in textbox its very simple create a class, set its property and in gridview add a databound with datakey as class property name, and while you click  on the button return the class as a list and set the datasource of the gridview to it and bind it.